# What is wrong with my function and callers? Button prompt with functions

Tags: javascript, function, leaflet

I am in a class for Web Mapping, and this assignment is really kicking my butt.I am completely new to this and have only been learning JS and such for three weeks now. So, the assignment is to have a map with markers for three cities and a button on the page that when the user clicks on it, they type in miles or km. And based on that input the function should be able to display population density based on KM or miles (depends on what they typed in). But right now it is giving me an error message that units is undefined. I emailed my professor and he was vague and basically said that units and my units caller was "randomly" placed.

I am just including the code with the caller and function portion of the assignment. The map part works fine.

```
var caller = mapCities(units)  

var button = document.getElementById("map-cities"); 
   button.addEventListener("click", function() {

       do {
           var units = prompt('Enter the units for calculating density', 'Enter "miles" or "km"');
       } while (units != "miles" && units != "km");

       mapCities(units);

  });



  function mapCities(units) { 

      var fortWayneDensity = CalcPopDensity(units, fortWayne.pop, fortWayne.areaMi, fortWayne.areaKm)
      var indyDensity = CalcPopDensity(units, indy.pop, indy.areaMi, indy.areaKm)
      var southBendDensity = CalcPopDensity(units, southBend.pop, southBend.areaMi, southBend.areaKm)
      // A density variable for each city representes a caller which sends down three pieces of information - units that was passed in through the MapCities caller and the pop and area from the objects you created above


      var fortWaynePopup = "<b>" + "Fort Wayne" + "</b><br>" +
              "<b>Density</b>: "+fortWayneDensity.toLocaleString()+" people per square " + units;
           var fortWayneMarker =
               L.marker(fortWayne.coord)
              .addTo(map)
              .bindPopup(fortWaynePopup);

      var indyPopup = "<b>" + "Indianapolis" + "</b><br>" +
              "<b>Density</b>: "+indyDensity.toLocaleString()+" people per square " + units;
           var indyMarker =
               L.marker(indy.coord)
              .addTo(map)
              .bindPopup(indyPopup);

      var southBendPopup = "<b>" + "South Bend" + "</b><br>" +
              "<b>Density</b>: "+southBendDensity.toLocaleString()+" people per square " + units;
           var southBendMarker =
               L.marker(southBend.coord)
              .addTo(map)
              .bindPopup(southBendPopup);


  }


   function CalcPopDensity (units, pop, areami, areakm){
       var choice = units;
       if (units = km) {
           pop/areakm}
       else {
           pop/areami}
       return choice
   }
```

Comment: Why do you call mapCities in the first line of the code? it will be called once someone will click the button

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to excecute:

```
var caller = mapCities(units)
```

but you declared units later:

```
var units = prompt('Enter the units for calculating density', 'Enter "miles" or "km"');
```

It should work if you delete your first line of code, since you are already executing the mapCities function inside the event listener.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {

   do {
       var units = prompt('Enter the units for calculating density', 'Enter "miles" or "km"');
   } while (units != "miles" && units != "km");

   mapCities(units);
```

});

if you really want to keep a reference to mapCities in the caller variable, you should do it this way:

```
var caller = mapCities
```

because if you use parenthesis it will execute the function, this way it keeps a reference to the function.

Comment: I deleted what you told me to delete and it gave me an error for km being undefined. But I figured it out, I needed to make km into 'km' in my if else statement. Now, it works! Thanks, internet.

Comment: I found another issue, my return statement in the last function was returning the miles or km instead of the pop density, this is how i fixed it ..                            
 function CalcPopDensity (units, pop, areami, areakm){
        var choice = units;
        if (units = 'km') { 
            return pop/areakm}
        else { 
            return pop/areami}